# Undefined reference and collect2: error: ld returned 1

Tags: c++

I don't understand why I have all this undefined reference error. All this definitions of functions and file.cpp and file.h are corrected and in the correct directory path. I have compiled in this way:

```
c++ -std=c++11 testpad.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/ad74.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/Cma.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/Cmapad.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/fpad.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/i2cConfDict.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/i2cdev.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/i2creg.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/i2cRegList.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/lm75.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/pad.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/PadBoard.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/PadConfigurator.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/padDefine.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/PadDev.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/PadDeviceMap.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/PadMeasures.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/PadPowerSwitch.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/pcf8575.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/prode.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/SectorConfigurator.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/ttcrx.cpp RPCi2ccan/CanChanFactory.cpp RPCi2ccan/i2cCanNode.cpp
```

and with g++ but nothing. This is the output error of my compilation:

```
/tmp/usertest/ccQQ70by.o: In function `CanChanFactory::getChannel(int, unsigned short, int)':
CanChanFactory.cpp:(.text+0x151): undefined reference to `CanInterface::newCanInterface(int, int, int, bool)'
/tmp/usertest/ccSmDSn9.o: In function `i2cCanNode::initChannel()':
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `CanNodeFactory::instance()'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `CanNodeFactory::getCanNode(int)'
/tmp/usertest/ccSmDSn9.o: In function `i2cCanNode::getELMBFirmwareVersion(unsigned char*)':
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x161): undefined reference to `CanNode::setNodeId(int)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x178): undefined reference to `getFirmwareVersion(CanNode*, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/usertest/ccSmDSn9.o: In function `i2cCanNode::getELMBHardwareVersion(unsigned char*)':
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x1a7): undefined reference to `CanNode::setNodeId(int)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x1be): undefined reference to `getHardwareVersion(CanNode*, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/usertest/ccSmDSn9.o: In function `i2cCanNode::NMTResetNode()':
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x26a): undefined reference to `CanNode::setNodeId(int)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x27f): undefined reference to `CanNode::nmt(int)'
/tmp/usertest/ccSmDSn9.o: In function `i2cCanNode::fast_init(int, int&)':
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x33a): undefined reference to `CanNode::setNodeId(int)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x361): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x3c3): undefined reference to `COP_ReadSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x476): undefined reference to `COP_ReadSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/usertest/ccSmDSn9.o: In function `i2cCanNode::read_error(unsigned char*)':
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x579): undefined reference to `CanNode::setNodeId(int)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x5a9): undefined reference to `read_init_error(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/usertest/ccSmDSn9.o: In function `i2cCanNode::check_locks(int)':
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x5e4): undefined reference to `read_check_locks(CanNode*, int)'
/tmp/usertest/ccSmDSn9.o: In function `i2cCanNode::read_i2c(int, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char*)':
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x77e): undefined reference to `CanNode::setNodeId(int)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x7a4): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x805): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x884): undefined reference to `COP_ReadSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x8ea): undefined reference to `COP_ReadSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/usertest/ccSmDSn9.o: In function `i2cCanNode::read_i2c_nomsg(int, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char*)':
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xa0c): undefined reference to `CanNode::setNodeId(int)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xa32): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xa77): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xada): undefined reference to `COP_ReadSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xb2b): undefined reference to `COP_ReadSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/usertest/ccSmDSn9.o: In function `i2cCanNode::write_i2c(int, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char*)':
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xbd4): undefined reference to `CanNode::setNodeId(int)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xc20): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xc81): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xcf0): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xd61): undefined reference to `COP_ReadSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/usertest/ccSmDSn9.o: In function `i2cCanNode::write_i2c_nomsg(int, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char*)':
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xe2e): undefined reference to `CanNode::setNodeId(int)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xe81): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xec6): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xf19): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xf72): undefined reference to `COP_ReadSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/usertest/ccSmDSn9.o: In function `i2cCanNode::write_i2c_suba(int, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char*)':
 i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0xfde): undefined reference to `CanNode::setNodeId(int)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x1020): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x1081): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x10e2): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x115b): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x11ca): undefined reference to `COP_ReadSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/usertest/ccSmDSn9.o: In function `i2cCanNode::read_i2c_suba(int, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char*)':
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x12d2): undefined reference to `CanNode::setNodeId(int)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x1321): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x1382): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x13e3): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x145b): undefined reference to `COP_ReadSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x14c1): undefined reference to `COP_ReadSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/usertest/ccSmDSn9.o: In function `i2cCanNode::cmreset()':
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x15b5): undefined reference to `CanNode::setNodeId(int)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x15dc): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/usertest/ccSmDSn9.o: In function `i2cCanNode::xilinx_init()':
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x1655): undefined reference to `CanNode::setNodeId(int)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x167b): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/usertest/ccSmDSn9.o: In function `i2cCanNode::polar_init()': 
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x16ed): undefined reference to `CanNode::setNodeId(int)'
i2cCanNode.cpp:(.text+0x1714): undefined reference to `COP_WriteSDO(CanNode*, int, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What's the trouble? Thanks at all.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "and with g++ but nothing"? What operating system? What do you get when you type `which c++` and `which g++`?

Comment: with g++ i have did this: g++ -std=c++11 testpad.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/ad74.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/Cma.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/Cmapad.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/fpad.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/i2cConfDict.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/i2cdev.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/i2creg.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/i2cRegList.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/lm75.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/pad.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/PadBoard.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/PadConfigurator.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/padDefine.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/PadDev.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/PadDeviceMap.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/PadMeasures.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/PadPowerSwitch.cpp  . The OS is Scientific Linux 6 and the same for c++ and g++

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a compiler error, but a linker error. It essentially states that in your source code `CanInterface::newCanInterface(int, int, int, bool)` is seen as an external symbol. And the linker does not find it anywhere hence the undefined symbol error.

You are probably missing a library. You specify libraries using the -L -l: in your build command.

Mind that there are no spaces after -L or -l:

Hope this sorts your problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a method for discover what is the missing library?

Comment: @LocalHero well, that is something you should know - where is the source code for that missing method? is it in a library you have not included or in a source file you have not included?

Answer (score 0):

Your command to compile is wrong

**c++ -std=c++11** testpad.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/ad74.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/Cma.cpp 
RPCgen_i2cprg/Cmapad.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/fpad.cpp

It should be

**g++ -std=c++11** testpad.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/ad74.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/Cma.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/Cmapad.cpp RPCgen_i2cprg/fpad.cpp

And you already stated in question

> with g++ but nothing